# What is the solution for speed for Year 15 "Shred Lines"?

Tags: 7-billion-humans

I'm playing 7 Billion Humans, and I'm stuck on finding the speed solution for year 15 "Shred Lines".

My current solution (for Size) runs in 26s, but i need to shave of 3 more seconds to get the Speed challenge.

[image]

Any pointers on how to make it in time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull both the `step`s out of the inner-loops, which saves two conditional-checks per outer-loop.

This works because there are no cubes directly above any worker's starting square:

[image: Puzzle starting conditions]

Answer (score 0):

**Speed:**

```
-- 7 Billion Humans (2056) --
-- 15: Shred Lines --

a:
b:
step n
if n == datacube:
    pickup n
else:
    jump b
endif
c:
step s
if s == shredder:
    giveto s
else:
    jump c
endif
jump a
```

**Size:**

```
-- 7 Billion Humans (2056) --
-- 15: Shred Lines --

a:
b:
if n != datacube:
    step n
    jump b
endif
pickup n
c:
if s != shredder:
    step s
    jump c
endif
giveto s
jump a
```

You can find all the solutions here: https://github.com/hingston/7-billion-humans-solutions/